# Would like to delete results from SQL Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-server-2012

I would like to delete results from a SQL Query.

Here is the query.

```
SELECT Name.ID, Name.FULL_NAME, Name.CHAPTER, Subscriptions.BEGIN_DATE, Name.MEMBER_TYPE, Subscriptions.PRODUCT_CODE
FROM   test.dbo.Name Name INNER JOIN test.dbo.Subscriptions Subscriptions ON (Name.ID=Subscriptions.ID) AND (Name.BT_ID=Subscriptions.BT_ID)
WHERE  Name.MEMBER_TYPE='DUPE'
ORDER BY Name.ID
```

Here is the Microsoft Versions I am using:

- Microsoft Windows 7
- SQL Server Management Studio 2012 11.0.3
- Operating System 6.1.7601

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Not such a trivial question, he's asking to delete rows from two tables

Comment: Are you looking to delete both entries in Name and Subscriptions. If only one table, which one?

Comment: A `DELETE` can only affect a single table at any one time unless there are foreign key constraints with cascade actions correctly set. Are you trying to delete from one table or both?

Comment: Looking to delete entries in the Subscriptions table.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're identifying rows by the `(ID, BT_ID)` pair.  Store that in a table variable:

```
declare @to_delete (id int, bt_id int);
insert  @to_delete
select  n.id
,       n.bt_id
from    Subscriptions s
join    Name n
on      n.id = s.id
        and n.bt_id = s.bt_id
where   n.member_type = 'DUPE'
```

Then delete from both tables:

```
delete  s
from    Subscriptions s
join    @to_delete td
on      td.id = s.id
        and td.bt_id = s.bt_id

delete  n
from    Name n
join    @to_delete td
on      td.id = n.id
        and td.bt_id = n.bt_id
```

Answer (score 0):

last answer on right track, but can make much simpler

```
SELECT Name.ID, Name.BT_ID
INTO #dump
FROM Name Name 
INNER JOIN Subscriptions Subscriptions 
   ON (Name.ID=Subscriptions.ID) AND (Name.BT_ID=Subscriptions.BT_ID)
WHERE  Name.MEMBER_TYPE='DUPE'

delete s from subscriptions s join #dump t on t.BT_ID = s.BT_ID and t.ID = s.ID
delete n from from Name n join #dump t on t.BT_ID = n.BT_ID and t.ID = n.ID
```

there is no reason to declare a temp table, just use the select to create it in scope only and the table drops off when you are done.  easy.